# SharePoint WebPart Custom Settings - Best Practise

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to ascertain what the best practise is for creating a SharePoint WebPart that has custom properties. I'll detail the background, because I might be doing this in completely the wrong way.

I've taken a DevExpress chart, which has a whole host of settings on there. I then decided to expose some of these settings and ended up with a WebPart that looked like:

```
public class MyWebPart : WebPart
{
   public DataTable { get; set; }
   public String ConnectionString { get; set; }
   public String Query { get; set; }

   public override void DataBind() 
   {
      UpdateMyTable(ConnectionString, Query);
      this.chartControl.DataSource = this.DataTable;
   }
}
```

I needed to add a whole load more settings onto this web part, a few single items that are strings, and others that correspond to a series (e.g. Binding values, Chart Type). So I moved the settings off the WebPart and ended up with something more akin to the following:

```
public class MyWebPart : WebPart
{
   public DataTable { get; set; }
   public ChartSettings { get; set; }

   public override void DataBind() 
   {
      UpdateMyTable(ConnectionString, Query);
      this.chartControl.DataSource = this.DataTable;
   }
}

public ChartSettings
{
    public List<SeriesSettings> Series { get; set; }
}
```

I made my settings classes Serializable and added a Personalizable attribute on the Property on my web part. This works fine via the web.

If I attempt to open the page in SharePoint designer however it complains that it can't create a ChartSettings (and DataTable) from their String representations. I've learnt that this is because the settings are exposed as Strings. Obviously the DataTable I can suppress the serialization of.

My question ultimately is, am I following the correct approach, moving settings onto a class? Or should I be leaving all the settings on my webpart (which would be messy keeping lots of series settings in different arrays), or is there a completely different approach? If you can point me to any references to support your suggestion (e.g. MSDN) then that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience (and some may disagree) has been to keep the WebPart as thin as possible.  WebParts seem to be awkward for things like: configuration, error handling and logging, tracing, etc.  I have found it much easier to put the bulk of my development into a WS (WebService/WCF) on localhost:8080.  The code in the webpart is simple: call the WS and let it do all of the work.  Config in the webpart is now simple because localhost is always easy to find.  Dev tools for WS/WCF are very strong.  Config, debugging, error handling, logging, tracing are all much simpler in WS/WCF.  Better still, I make a simple jig (Winform/Webform) to call/test my WS layer.  With this architecture, you put your code where your dev tools are strongest.  It is similar to the rationale behind the MVC pattern.

Comment: Oh.  One other recommendation that I have heard from a SP2010 MVP is to serialize your configs to XML and put that in a SP folder.  It would resolve your issue without changing your current app architecture very much.

Comment: I did consider that actually, and thought if I could get the XML to look like: <webpart><settings connectionString="x" query="y"/></webpart> rather than <webpart settings="<xml version=1.0><Settings connectionString="x"/>"> then I think it would be useful as you'd easily be able to edit via HTML or the SharePoint editor. Do you know how to produce this structure?